# Acute and chronic are sub-classification of what?

Tags: word-request

We can classify a disease for example according to the **severity** (mild, intermediate, and severe) or according to the **stability** (stable and non-stable) and so on. According to **what** we determine acute and chronic?

Answer (score 1):

The symptomatic timeframe of the disease from onset through healing can be described as acute or chronic. Acute can mean that the disease has a short symptomatic cycle. The disease comes on quickly and can be healed quickly (in a matter of weeks). Chronic can mean the disease will remain symptomatic over a long period of time. It may last through the rest of the patient’s life. There may be times of greater or lesser severity in a chronic disease. But, it is always present for the possibilities of flare-ups.

Comment: You might want to edit  in the concept of the acute exacerbation of a chronic condition which may help to clarify even further.

Answer (score 0):

Usually they are classified under the phases or stages of a disease.

Classification:
According to the **phase** or **stage** of disease:  1. Acute.  2. Chronic.

See also here: stage of the condition (https://www.physio-pedia.com/Stage_of_the_Condition)